# What's the relationship between a $E_2$-Hochschild Cohomology module and a D-module?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, d-modules, higher-algebra

Let's say for simplicity $A$ is a smooth algebra over a field $k$ ($A$ and $k$ are discrete commutative rings but from now on we are fully derived), and we will consider the $E_2$ algebra $HH^{\bullet}(A)$ which I'll just call $H_A$. We know by HKR it carries $T_A$ the tangent module in cohomological degree 1 and wedges of it in higher degrees and that the $E_2$ structure gives $T_A$ the normal Lie bracket structure and allows it to act on $A$.

Now let's suppose we have $H_A$ acting on $M$ which is concentrated in degree $0$ as a $E_2$ module. As for the homotopy groups of an $E_2$ algebra, it seems to me that $M$ should inherit both a action of $H_A$ normally and a degree lowering (sort of Lie bracket) action. More precisely, as $E_2$ algebra's homotopy groups inherit Gerstenhaber structure I'm guessing that $M$ will inherit a similar thing. (One supporting evidence is that the space of maps $H_A \otimes M \to M$ should be parametrized by 2 marked 2-discs in a 2-disc so there's an $S^1$ worth of such maps giving a degree lowering map of spectra)

Now assuming the above is correct, $M$ should have a D-module structure. (Does this seem correct?) One example of a $M$ is $A$ itself, which should inherit the standard D-module structure.

The question, assuming the above, is what class of D-modules is recoverable from this procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Incorporated David Ben-Zvi's comments below.)

An $E_2$-$\mathrm{HH}^\bullet(A)$-module is the same as a left module over the algebra of Hochschild chains $\mathrm{HH}_\bullet(\mathrm{HH}^\bullet(A))$.

Now assume $k$ has characteristic zero. It was shown by Tamarkin and Tsygan (see Theorem 2.7.1 in "The ring of differential operators on forms in noncommutative calculus") that this algebra is $A_\infty$ equivalent to $D(\Omega^\bullet(A))$, differential operators on differential forms on $A$ (with the zero differential and homologically graded). However, there is no natural morphism $D(A)\rightarrow D(\Omega^\bullet(A))$.

Here is another way to compute it. Suppose $H$ is an $E_2$-algebra. Then the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{LMod}_H$ of left modules over $H$ (viewed as an $E_1$-algebra) is monoidal; this uses the Dunn--Lurie additivity theorem of $E_n$ algebras, see Corollary 5.1.2.6 in Higher Algebra. I claim that the Drinfeld center of $\mathrm{LMod}_H$ is exactly the category of $E_2$-$H$-modules. One way to see it is to consider the corresponding framed 2d TFT; the value on the circle is the Drinfeld center which can be computed using factorization homology of $H$.

Now, let's say $A$ is a commutative dg algebra concentrated in non-positive degrees and $X=\mathrm{Spec}\ A$ the corresponding derived affine scheme. The monoidal category $\mathrm{LMod}_{\mathrm{HH}^\bullet(A)}$ is equivalent to the monoidal category $\mathbb{H}(A)$ defined in https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.03752 (see Section 4.1 for the precise claim). Its Drinfeld center is computed in https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07867 to be $\mathfrak{D}^{der}(LX)$, a variant of the derived category of $D$-modules on the derived loop space $LX = X\times_{X\times X} X$.

If $X$ is smooth, $LX$ is eventually coconnective; so, by Example 0.2.5 $\mathfrak{D}^{der}(LX) = \mathfrak{D}(LX)$ is the usual derived category of $D$-modules on $LX$. (Note that $\mathfrak{D}(LX) = \mathfrak{D}(T[-1] X)$ which agrees with the Tamarkin--Tsygan computation.) The latter satisfies Kashiwara's lemma, i.e. it is insensitive to the derived structure. In particular, the natural pushforward functor along constant loops $\mathfrak{D}(X)\rightarrow \mathfrak{D}(LX)$ is an equivalence.

Comment: I'm probably missing something obv but if u're forgetting the dR differential isn't there an evident map D(A) - - - >D(\Omega_A), coming from the fact that A is a retract of \Omega?

Comment: @EBz: the only homomorphism $D(A)\rightarrow D(\Omega^\bullet(A))$ I can imagine requires one to choose a flat connection on the tangent bundle. Then you send a vector field on $A$ to the covariant derivative acting on differential forms. Conversely, any homomorphism lifting the obvious inclusion $A\rightarrow \Omega^\bullet(A)$, compatible with the filtration and compatible with the action on $A$ is the same as a flat connection on the tangent bundle.

Comment: @davik: said another way, this is the algebra of differential operators on the graded vector bundle $T[-1]$. This is the usual (underived) definition of differential operators where you take care of the gradings. The zero section is a closed subvariety of the tangent bundle, so there are standard D-module functorialities (pushforward and pullback) realized by certain bimodules between $D(A)$ and $D(\Omega^\bullet(A))$.

Comment: Is there a natural map in the opposite direction? Also it may be possible to acquire a D module action via another Morita like way but maybe it's unlikely. In any case I still think it's possible that degree 0 modules of the right ring could inherit D module structures somehow using that's it's in one degree, but maybe it's superficial

Comment: @pavel ofc u are absolutely correct, thanks!

Comment: @PavelSafronov I just saw your comment, thanks. This makes a lot of sense. I'll think about what was wrong with my argument above, because to me it doesn't seem like there's a very natural bimodule to take here, maybe A itself is the only candidate very natural bimodule I can think of....

Comment: @PavelSafronov For $A$ smooth the functorialities you mention give a derived equivalence between $D$-modules on $Spec(A)$ and on its shifted tangent bundle (since the latter is a nilpotent thickening of the former) -- how much more generally will that hold? (eg if $T[-1]$ is eventually coconnective?)

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi: thanks for the comment! The result that David has in mind is a more modern computation of $E_2$-$\mathrm{HH}^\bullet(A)$-modules as the Drinfeld center of a certain monoidal category $\mathbb{H}(A)$ in https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07867. In particular, Section 4.3 discusses a relationship (if $T[-1]$ is eventually coconnective) to the usual derived category of $D$-modules which has the relevant homotopy invariance property (Kashiwara's Lemma).

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi Wait so for A smooth is the conclusion that you get an equivalence between the two categories??

Comment: @PavelSafronov I think I understand less than you claim. Is it clear why $E_2-HH^\bullet$-modules agree with Beraldo's "derived D-modules"? in particular when you wrote D-modules on $T[-1]$, I thought it was ordinary D-modules not the sheared / derived version Beraldo uses? in any case in the eventually coconnective case they should all agree

Comment: or are you saying something general about an $E_2$-functor from $E_2$-modules for an algebra vs the Drinfeld center of its monoidal category of left modules?

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand your claim about the Drinfeld center but not the proof, I thought evaluation on the circle gives Hochschild homology so I guess here there's some mechanism which is equating homology with cohomology? Tbh in the first paper you linked 4.1.6 it says the equivalence between bold H and HC is obvious which I don't entirely see why, but I guess this all must be covered by the computations in the second paper.