# Two vague questions about TFT

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, topological-quantum-field-theory

**Question 1.** Take a smooth projective Calabi-Yau $X$. Then $D^b(X)$ is a fully-dualizable category and there's an associated 2d TFT. This the usual 2d B-model with target $X$.

But $D^b(X)$ is actually a monoidal category, so there's a 2-category $D^b(X)$-mod of categories with an action of $D^b(X)$. Apparently this 2-category is also fully-dualizable, and it defines a 3d TFT. This is the Rozansky-Witten theory with target $T^*X$. (Here I'm just repeating words I've been told.)

But $D^b(X)$ is actually symmetric monoidal, so $D^b(X)$-mod is monoidal, so there's a 3-category ($D^b(X)$-mod)-mod. Does this give us a 4d TFT? And if so does this ever stop? $\mathcal{O}_X$ is genuinely commutative (or $E_\infty$) so for every $n$ there should be an $n$-category of modules over modules over $\;$ ...$\;$ over modules over $\mathcal{O}_X$. So potentially an $n$-d TFT.

Does this (a) work, and (b) produce anything interesting?

And a related:

**Question 2.** Evaluating an $n$-d TFT on the $n-1$ sphere apparently gives us an $E_n$-algebra. If the $n$-d theory came from modules over ... an $E_{n-1}$ algebra then this is some version of taking the centre. For example the 2d B-model on $X$, evaluated on $S^1$, produces the $E_2$ algebra $HH^*(X)$.

What happens if I take modules over modules over ... this $E_n$ algebra? If I'm lucky I might get a dualizable $n$-category and then an $(n+1)$-TFT.

Does this work in general? (Presumably not). Does it ever work?

For example is there a 3d TFT arising from modules over modules over the $E_2$-algebra $HH^*(X)$, and if so does it have a name?

Answer (score 11):

I will only attempt to answer the first question.

Given a symplectic manifold $M$, there is a TQFT in any odd dimension. In dimension 1 this is the topological quantum mechanics and in dimension 3 this is the Rozansky--Witten theory. In higher dimensions these have no name and do not arise from topological twists of supersymmetric sigma-models. These are all examples of AKSZ theories.

If you squint your eyes, you can think of $M=B G$ as a symplectic manifold. The corresponding TQFTs are the Chern--Simons theories: in 1d it is the theory considered in https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2111, in 3d is is the usual Chern--Simons theory, in 5d it is the theory considered in https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.02841 (a topological twist of 5-dimensional superysmmetric Yang--Mills). In higher dimensions it again does not arise from topological twisting.

Given any manifold $X$ you can consider $M=T^* X$. So, you get TQFTs associated to any manifold $X$. These will not be fully defined in the top dimension as $M$ is noncompact. For $M = T^* BG$ these are called the BF theories.

Similarly, if you have an odd symplectic manifold $M$, you get the AKSZ TQFT in any even dimension. E.g. for $M = \Pi T^* X$ for a manifold $X$ you get the $B$-model.

To conclude: the TQFTs you mention (obtained from $D^b(X)$ as a symmetric monoidal category) exist in any dimension. The partition functions will not be well-defined in dimensions $\dim\geq 3$ (the corresponding object is not fully dualizable), but they have interesting spaces of states, categories etc.

Comment: How do you show that the higher-dimensional Chern-Simons theories don't arise from topological twisting? (Or, more generally, why do the odd-dimensional TQFTs associated to symplectic manifolds not arise as topological twists?)

Comment: Fantastic thanks Pavel!  I wasn't sure if anyone was still looking at MO...

Comment: That is a pretty comprehensive answer to part 1. For part 2, I wouldn't be surprised if E_2 modules (properly understood) over HH(X) are equivalent to D(X), and maybe that's all that happens. But I'm kind of guessing here.

Comment: @skd: the only explanation I have is that people have computed twists of nonlinear gauged sigma-models and the higher-dimensional Chern--Simons/RW theories do not arise. It might be possible that they arise from twisting some higher spin theories, but I know much less about them.

Comment: @EdSegal: the 2-category $\mathrm{HH}^\bullet(X)\mathrm{-mod}\mathrm{-mod}$ is extensively studied by Dario Beraldo in relation to singular support of coherent sheaves. If $X$ is smooth, then $\mathrm{HH}^\bullet(X)\mathrm{-mod}\mathrm{-mod}$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{ShvCat}(X_{dR})$, the 2-category of crystals of categories over $X$. I don't know a good name for the corresponding 3d TQFT.

Comment: @EdSegal  Two comments of things I learned from Pavel:
First as to E_2 modules over HH^*, it's close but not D(X) in general, see Pavel's answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371637/whats-the-relationship-between-a-e-2-hochschild-cohomology-module-and-a-d-mod/371647#371647

Comment: Second, one POV on the field theory you're asking about (generated by HH^*(X)) is that it's a (or the) {\it theory of observables} for the B-model. In general any TFT is canonically defined relative to a (truncated) TFT of one dimension higher defined using observables (in your case, local operators). The former we think of as describing states, the latter expresses observables (eg as captured in the Costello-Gwilliam formalism by evaluating factorization homology of a factorization algebra).

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi Thanks for the link! I don't understand much of Pavel's answer to that other question but it looks like the kind of thing I wanted. I'll ask Dario...